# MS CRM 2013 Search & Add Entity Record in CRM Form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have 2 entities Entity **A** & **B**.

In Entity **A**, I have created a form. In this form I want to add a Grid Type Control which will have Add button to add Records from Entity **B**.

I am new to this CRM 2013 form making. Tried searching over internet but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: @JamesWood. Yes, 2. Corrected now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are some keywords to get you started:

- You want to create a **[1:N-relationship](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531171.aspx#BKMK_CreateEditN1Relationships)** between Entity A and Entity B
- Then you want to add a **sub-grid** of Entity B-records to Entity A's form.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bUpOUe1bR8) walks through adding a sub-grid to a form.